# Hibernate LAZY Fetch VS Optimistic Locking version

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Sorry if the answer was already response, but I tried to find out the solution and I could not find anything clear yet.

My question is, there´s any relationships between LAZY fetch relationships, which I know they have the control to know if they have to JOIN or not to other entities or initialize from database if they´re dirty on session, with the principle of optimistic locking VERSION?.

As far as I can understand the optimistic locking VERSION is more necessary if we have to handle multiple transactions at the same time. Is that correct?.

If all the transactions that we do in our applications are done sequentially, it is enough use LAZY fetch to manage when JOINS have to being done?. Or add version give us any add of value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two completely disparate concepts. You only hit a "lazy load" if you get or set a lazily loaded relationship.

If you're using optimistic locking and your row is on V2, it just prevents submission of a modified V2 from one client (which results in the version being upped to 3) and then a different V2 from another client, forcing them to reload the data and submit a later version.

If your logic hits the lazily loaded relationships which then hit thousands of other relationships and ends up loading millions of rows, you will have a performance problem, not a versioning one. In which case you may need to up your batch sizes or maybe do some fetch joins to ensure whatever it is you want is loaded in one block rather than thousands of sequential SQL queries.

So, different problem spaces entirely.

If you're trying to update a very complex object graph, where your alterations go deep into that graph, you may hit interesting optimistic locking problems as ensuring an entire tree's "version" is the same is difficult.

UPDATE: For clarification.

If you have a Car (which has singular properties such as make, model, registration number) and Wheels in multiple. This would be a 1:0..n relationship, represented as two tables, a Car table and a Wheel table, where the Wheel has an FK back to Car. (For the purposes of this post, we will ignore many-to-many relationships).

If you lazy load your wheels, then unless you're interested if you have rim spinners, tyres, locking nuts etc, you never need load the Wheel records in, they're not relevant if you only need the registration number.

Your Car record is on V1, it has a registration number of AB1212

If I, as the Vehicle registrar of Moldova update it to AC4545 and submit with V1 (the current version), I will succeed and the version number will be incremented. I will not hit the Wheels unless I need to. If at the same time, the Subaltern Vehicle registrar in the other room tries to do the same thing on V1, it will fail with an StaleObjectException, again, not hitting the Wheels and thus not invoking a lazy load.

Comment: But then, if I understand what you said, if I have all my relationships as LAZY, have optimistic locking is redundant right?.

Comment: " the Subaltern Vehicle registrar in the other room" is another transaction right?. But as I explain in my case, there´s no concurrent transactions, so this issue is never possible, so optimistic locking is redundant. Sorry if I continue missing something :)

Answer (score 0):

The lazy fetch proxy will throw a LazyInitializationException if it tries to fetch data that was altered by a different transaction(if that happens) with optimistic locking.

It's hard to help without any code or a good question, but as long as you keep all your initializations within a `@Transactional` code block, you should encounter much trouble.

That being said, you are trying to compare two (functionally) very different things...

Hope this helps.